# how to select all records containing certain values from a postgres json field containig an array

Tags: postgresql

I have `tableA` containing a json field `data`. abstracted examples for field `data`:

```
{"sequence": [123,456,789]}
{"sequence": [456,789]}
{"sequence": [789, 12]}
```

**update:** added sqlfiddle with some sample data -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/62475/24

with

```
select * from tableA where (data->'sequence') @> '[456]';
```

I am able to select all records containing `456`:

```
{"sequence": [123,456,789]}
{"sequence": [456,789]}
```

I am struggling to select all records containing `123` or `456`. is this possible?

it would also be useful to include `123` or `456` as a subquery like:

```
select * from tableA where (data->'sequence') in (select data_id from tableB);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ANY` to to test if the jsonb array contains *any* of the right values, which can be an array or a subquery, *using your sqlfiddle example*

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA
WHERE (data->'sequence') @> ANY(SELECT (data_id::TEXT)::JSONB FROM tableB)
```

You can also pass an array literal, in this case it would require an array of JSONB values, i.e. the right side of `@>` could be replaced with the literal `ANY('{123,456}'::JSONB[])`

Alternatively, Use the `&&` to test for array overlap. It is first necessary to convert the JSON/JSONB array to a native array

```
SELECT tableA.*
FROM tableA 
JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(v::INT) y 
  FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TEXT(data->'sequence') v
) x ON TRUE
WHERE x.y && '{123, 456}'
```

You can also replace the array literal `'{123, 456}'` with a subquery that returns an array of integers, such as `(SELECT ARRAY_AGG(data_id) FROM tableB)`

Another option would be to use or in your where clause

```
select *
from tableA 
where (data->'sequence') @> '[456]'
   or (data->'sequence') @> '[123]'
```

Comment: thanks ali. yes, of course but too "manual". actually I have a case wher I have to check for 43 different ids. unfortunately adding them manually as you suggested is not an option :|
I added a sqlfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/62475/24). how would you extend this with `any`?

Comment: see updated answer, don't know why I didn't immediately think of this solution

Comment: Unfortunately the `&&` operator only works with native arrays, not with JSON arrays.

Comment: yups -> _operator does not exist_. the `any` suggestion is probably the way to go so the values to check against can be retrieved by a subquery...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for catching that. You could always expand & array_agg to obtain a native array which does support `&&`.

Comment: ali, you rock. I'm deeply impressed!