# How can I select records that match a value in a json field array?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I'm trying to return records matching an array element that equals a specific value from a json field.

I found [how to select all records containing certain values from a postgres json field containig an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57564309/how-to-select-all-records-containing-certain-values-from-a-postgres-json-field-c) that is close to my question. However, I think the key difference is I use json and not jsonb. For reasons, I need to use json at the moment. When I tried the steps from that other post, I get the same error as below.

I have this example `data`

```
{"name": "Bob", "scores": [64, 66]}
{"name": "Sally", "scores": [66, 65]}
{"name": "Kurt", "scores": [69, 71, 72, 67, 68]}
{"name": "Libby", "scores": [72, 73, 74, 75]}
{"name": "Frank", "scores": [80, 81, 82, 83]}
```

I'm trying to run this query:

```
SELECT data
FROM tests.results
where (data->>'scores') @> '[72]';
```

I expect two rows from the results:

```
{"name": "Kurt", "scores": [69, 71, 72, 67, 68]}
{"name": "Libby", "scores": [72, 73, 74, 75]}
```

but I get:

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: text @> integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). 
  You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I currently using Postgres 10, but am likely upgrading to 12. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to use `->` instead of `->>`. The former returns a json object, while the latter returns text; meanwhile, the `@>` operator operates on json objects, not on text.

```
SELECT data
FROM tests.results
where (data->'scores')::jsonb @> '[72]';
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5X2nss3o1MBp6K8SmTmd6c/0)**:

```
WITH results AS (
    SELECT '{"name": "Bob", "scores": [64, 66]}'::json mydata
    UNION ALL SELECT '{"name": "Sally", "scores": [66, 65]}'::json
    UNION ALL SELECT '{"name": "Kurt", "scores": [69, 71, 72, 67, 68]}'::json
    UNION ALL SELECT '{"name": "Libby", "scores": [72, 73, 74, 75]}'::json
    UNION ALL SELECT '{"name": "Frank", "scores": [80, 81, 82, 83]}'::json
)
SELECT mydata::text
FROM results
where (mydata->'scores')::jsonb @> '[72]';

| mydata                                           |
| ------------------------------------------------ |
| {"name": "Kurt", "scores": [69, 71, 72, 67, 68]} |
| {"name": "Libby", "scores": [72, 73, 74, 75]}    |
```

Comment: The documentation I saw says that `@>` is a jsonb only operator -- will this work? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html  He probably needs to do a find on the string value.

Comment: @Hogan: ah ok I see, I updated my answer accordingly and added a fiddle.

Comment: That's it! Thanks guys. Changing the ->> to -> and adding ::jsonb in my where clause did it. Appreciate the quick turnaround.